# When recyclerview item click , save data for recyclerview position to firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am beginner in Android. I want to save data to firebase with recycler view position . For example , I am "A" user and when i click recycler view item (it is "B" user) ,I get "B"'s user UID and save "A" user's data like "kullanici","sifre" (see example):

[image]

```
final RecyclerView recyclerView2 = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView2.addOnItemTouchListener(
    new RecyclerItemClickListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView2 ,new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Long Click"+ epostaList.get(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            String value = (String) recyclerView2.getVerticalScrollbarPosition(position);


            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
            databaseReference.child(resgisterpage.cinsiyyet.toString()).child("connections").child("yeps").child(resgisterpage.userId).setValue(true);


            // FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() ;
            // Toast.makeText(context, "" + currentFirebaseUser.getUid(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            //Toast.makeText(context,"Kayıt Başarılı.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
            // do whatever


        }
    })
);
```